# CSS - prevent elements from pushing

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent elements inside a div from pushing each other, I have my progress bar hidden until the event(drop) is called, and my img menu always visible

example:

[image]

as you can see, my progress bar is pushing down my img menu, I want both of them inside my div

how can I fix this?

code:

```
<div class="container2">
    <h2>Foto en toga</h2>
    <div class="PhotoContainer">
        <div class="drop" id="d1">
            <?php include ('inc/progressbar.php'); ?>
            <?php include ('inc/imagemenu.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

progressbar.php :

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                <span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

imagemenu.php:

```
<div class="imgmenu">

<div class="btn btn-default custombtnview">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<div class="btn btn-default custombtnremove">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.drop{
border:4px dotted #bdc3c7;
padding:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
width:200px;
height:290px;
float: left;
margin: 20px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.imgmenu {

width: 60%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 140%;


}

.imgview {
float: left;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
background-color: aqua;
}

.imgclear {
float: left;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
background-color: blueviolet;
}

.progress {
margin-top: 70%;
left: 0;

}
```

Comment: Set position: absolute for the images and align them accordingly.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: @fmt can you view mobile version inside jsfiddle? I don't think so

Comment: Is it so, then you should try out position absolute for class imagemenu.

Comment: sorry I didn't mention this, I'm setting the image droped as background

Comment: It doesn't matter, then set the tag which is using images as a background, to absolute. After that, example: top: 200px; left/right also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `absolute`ly positioned elements for this kind of requirements.

Just a few things to remember..

1. For the `position:absolute` to work, the `position` for the parent element should be set (anything other than `static`(*default*)) or else it will take the position of the first ancestor that has the position set and if not then by default the position of the `body` is taken as an anchor.
2. To set the element into a specific location you can use the attributes `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`.

Comment: I made my parent's position:relative (.drop) and my .progress position:absolute, but now my progress bar is behind the .drop div

Comment: figured it out, I wasn't giving my container a dimension, Thanks a lot