# Image not getting centered horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have created a modal using html , css and JavaScript

i have added a image having class "pic"

When you will open modal window , you will see the image at the top

In css , i have defined the class pic  ..[ display:block; and margin: auto ; ]
still its not being centered horizontally.

Whole codings are attached below

```js
$(function(){

// Get the button that opens the modal
// read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #171B20;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #F0B823;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #171B20;
    color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {
}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
   font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px 15px;                                                                                                       
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 35%;
 }
}

p {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
          <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
          <p>Body Text Comes here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - prevent elements from pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828304/css-prevent-elements-from-pushing)

Comment: Image is not horizontally centered because of  close button is set to float. Try adding position:absolute on the close button.

Comment: @Kaddath thanks for that , i will surely have a look .  I am a newbie ,  not so well versed with position attribute of CSS.

Comment: @MdJunaidAlam thanks for commenting, i have understood the fix.  , i gotta learn the position attribute properly

Comment: I corrected it by mistake with my edit, but you had one too many closing `</div>` in your code in case you didn't see it. (and it carried in the accepted answer too)

Comment: @Kaddath thanks for noticing that and correcting it , i believe there was one extra closing tag , earlier there were 5 of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check Updated Code..

```js
$(function(){

// Get the button that opens the modal
// read all the control of any type which has class as modal-button
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #171B20;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
 color: #F0B823;
 float: right;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: absolute;
 right: 20px;
 top: 0;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #171B20;
    color: #F0B823;
}

.modal-body {
}

.modal-button {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  background-color: #171B20; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.modal-button:hover {
  background-color: #171B20;
  color: #F0B823;
}

.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

.headertext {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bodytext {
   font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
   display: block;
   padding: 10px 15px;                                                                                                       
}

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
.pic {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 35%;
 }
}

p {
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">• Click Me</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <div class="headertext">
          <p>Modal Header</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img class="pic" src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=108ZLeoIfNkKODfRbLuPWpmXRl0gH9qkD">
      <div class="bodytext">
          <p>Body Text Comes here</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be better if it was not a code only answer. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If your image is at 60% width, set the left attribute to 20% with absolute positioning.

```
.pic {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 60%;
}
```